# Best way to check multiple equalities?

Tags: python

Preferably in Python,

What's the best way to create a function that checks for multiple equalities? I want the function to return 1 if the input is equal to "f", "fall", "F", "Fall", "fa", etc. and if "fall" is in a dictionary.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by multiple equalities? That is starts with the given letter, case-insensitive? Or that it contains it? In any case, this looks like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: You should add a few examples with your input and expected output to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing a bit, it sounds like you have a dictionary of words (commands?) and want to match the first entry that matches partial input, case-insensitive:

```
D = dict(fall=None,stand=None)
trials = 'f fall F Fall fa foo Foo s ST stan'.split()

def check(t):
    for k in D:
        if k.startswith(t.lower()):
            return k
    return None

for t in trials:
    print '{0:7}{1}'.format(t,check(t))
```

#### Output

```
f      fall
fall   fall
F      fall
Fall   fall
fa     fall
foo    None
Foo    None
s      stand
ST     stand
stan   stand
```

Comment: `if k.lower().startswith(t.lower())` would mean you could use keys with uppercase characters.

Comment: @senderle, yes but is less efficient.  Better to store keys already lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pythonic version using `filter` combined with 'len > 1' ....

```
input = "fall"
the_list = ["f", "fall", "F", "Fall", "fa"]
your_test = len(filter(lambda x: x == input, the_list)) > 1 \
       and "fall" in your_dictionary
```

Comment: That's not pythonic. It's python code and it works, but it's neither particular idiomatic nor the shortest/most performant (complexity-wise - `filter` is still linear in the best case, @pboothe's solution stops after one comparision in the best case).

Comment: I don't think I have said that this is the most effective solution ... have I ? . If you like @pboothe's answer upvote it. I think your comment has nothing to do with the question where nothing about complexity was stated.